# Is there a way to specify webSessionManager when using WebTestClientAutoConfiguration?

Tags: kotlin, spring-test, spring-webflux

I am using Webflux in Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE to create REST API. With that implementation, I customize and use the *webSessionManager* as below.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun webSessionManager(): WebSessionManager {
        return DefaultWebSessionManager().apply {
            sessionIdResolver = HeaderWebSessionIdResolver().apply {
                headerName = "X-Sample"
            }
            sessionStore = InMemoryWebSessionStore()
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in order to test the REST API, I created a test code as follows. (`addUser` and `signin` are extension functions.)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
class UserTests {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var client: WebTestClient

    @Test
    fun testGetUserInfo() {
        client.addUser(defaultUser)
        val sessionKey = client.signin(defaultUser)

        client.get().uri(userPath)
                .header("X-Sample", sessionKey)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
                .expectBody()
                .jsonInStrict("""
                {
                  "user": {
                    "mail_address": "user@example.com"
                  }
                }
                """.trimIndent())
    }

    // ...
}
```

The test failed. It is refused by authorization. However, if I start the server and run it from `curl` it will succeed in the authorization.

After investigating the cause, it turned out that `org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.AbstractMockServerSpec` set *webSessionManager* to `DefaultWebSessionManager`. Default is used, not the *webSessionManager* I customized. For this reason, it could not get the session ID.

- [AbstractMockServerSpec.java#L41](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c2a5fcd3538e031525d3656f1b7c9d5f4702ee06/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/AbstractMockServerSpec.java#L41)
- [AbstractMockServerSpec.java#L72-L78](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c2a5fcd3538e031525d3656f1b7c9d5f4702ee06/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/AbstractMockServerSpec.java#L72-L78)

**How can I change the webSessionManager of AbstractMockServerSpec?**

Also, I think that it is better to have the following implementation, what do you think?

```
abstract class AbstractMockServerSpec<B extends WebTestClient.MockServerSpec<B>>
        implements WebTestClient.MockServerSpec<B> {

    // ...

    private WebSessionManager sessionManager = null;

    // ...

    @Override
    public WebTestClient.Builder configureClient() {
        WebHttpHandlerBuilder builder = initHttpHandlerBuilder();
        builder.filters(theFilters -> theFilters.addAll(0, this.filters));
        if (this.sessionManager != null) {
            builder.sessionManager(this.sessionManager);
        }
        this.configurers.forEach(configurer -> configurer.beforeServerCreated(builder));
        return new DefaultWebTestClientBuilder(builder);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: this looks like a Spring Boot enhancement request rather than a SO question - could you create an issue on the Spring Boot tracker?

Comment: Yes, I will create. Thanks!

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Framework's `AbstractMockServerSpec` is providing a method to customize the `WebSessionManager` already.

Thanks for opening [SPR-17094](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17094), this problem will be solved with that ticket - the `AbstractMockServerSpec` is already looking into the application context for infrastructure bits, this should check for a `WebSessionManager` as well.